# Django update object - validator

Tags: python, json, django, validation

I have an AJAX request that updates a model object. It sends the new value in a dict, like:

```
new_value = {'attribute': 'value'}
```

I'm using the method update() to save the new value:

```
.update(**new_value)
```

It saves the object fine, but it's skipping my MinValueValidator:

```
field = models.DecimalField(... validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.01'))])
```

How could I make this validator work with update()? It works good from the admin.

Comment: It never will, validators are for forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sayse wrote in comment validators will only work in forms (also admin forms).

You can achieve what you need by overriding `save()` method for your model. Just check if value is ok, otherwise throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of updating my object with updating() I ended up extracting the data from the dict and calling seattr with field.clean:

```
field = item._meta.get_field(attribute)
setattr(item, attribute, field.clean(attr_value, item))
```

This way the validator is thrown correctly.

To override the model save() method to validate a field and throw an exception may not be the best practice from what I have read. Perhaps, writing a clean method for it in the model is a better approach. Anyway, [Michał Werner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2395401/micha%C5%82-werner)'s answer seems to address what I asked.